# How to solve package installation problems and grant permissions to files

Tags: linux, permissions, terminal

How to solve package installation problems and grant permissions to files.

Hello Recently 2 days ago I installed Linux, "Linux mint 21.1"
The first day what I did was just update my repositories with the command.
sudo apt upgrade

The next day that I wanted to install DNSmasq I find that the password is incorrect. The only password I have is
what
When trying to modify some rules of

```
/etc/password

/etc/shadow

sudoers
```

use commands

```
sudo

su-

chmod

chown
```

But I can neither modify rules nor use the commands because everything tells me that the password is incorrect.
I'm thinking of modifying this from grub, but I don't know how I could do this.
My other question is that if these are due to package updates, the repositories are from ubuntu, I know this through the graphical interface that indicated the repositories, which linux mint used.

Comment: `the password is incorrect.` which one? you can clearly log in to your system so that password seems correct, so which password is "incorrect"?

Comment: How did you modify `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, and `/etc/sudoers`? These are really important system files. Please tell us [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/744428/edit) what commands you used and what exactly you changed

Comment: When I log in through the graphical interface to the desktop I write my password which is
q
But in the terminal I can't enter that password using sudo, su- therefore I can't change any rules of a file.

Comment: I haven't modified anything, I just updated the repositories, but then nothing could be downloaded from the repositories, and in several tutorials it mentions modifying the /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, and /etc/sudoers files I wanted to edit but it shows me that the operation cannot be performed, I cannot read write or execute

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` by itself doesn't do anything, you should see a usage message.

`su-` should give you a **command not found** error.

Since `sudo apt upgrade` worked, you must be in a group with sudo-privileges and the password must be correct.

Try `sudo apt install dnsmasq` ...